# When did the meaning of shi 是 shift from »this« (此) to being a copula (»be«)?

Tags: etymology, word, classical-chinese

I know this question is somewhat unclear since the word *shi* 是 never **only** meant *this*, but carries (and has done so for a long time) several meanings.
The Gu Hanyu da cidian (via Pleco) lists some of them (not a direct quote; the numbers denote the century of the sources that the example sentences were taken from):

> 正確(5)；訂正(3)；以爲是(-4)；表示肯定或加強肯定之詞(-3) etc.

But very generally speaking, *shi* was used in the language of the Lunyu (which I call here Classical Chinese) to denote »this« rather than any of its other meanings.

But when did *shi* start to mainly have the meaning as a copula that it has today, *to be*, as in »She is a student«, »Those are books«?

Comment: The specific reason I ask is: I have a sentence from a 16th century text by Luo Rufang (Luo Jinxi) and I’m not clear about a 是 in it, but that would be a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from the 2017 paper "Some New Insight into the Historical Source of the Chinese Copula Shì/*deʔ 是 ":

> Wang (1937) claims that there was no genuine copula in the Chinese language until the emergence of the copula *shì* / *deʔ 是 around the 5th century — a dating he later modified to the 1st century (Wang 1958) — evolving from the demonstrative shì.

That is the general consensus, and this idea has been established for the best part of 80 years.

However, there is the statement that:

> [S]ome later studies, especially those based on excavated materials (Qiu 1979; Tang 1991), argue that the copular use of *shì* starts from the Warring States period (475–221 BCE).

Li and Thompson (1977) is the classic source for citing this well-trodden pathway cross-linguistically:

> TOPIC - COMMENT > SUBJECT - PREDICATE
>
> [NP1] - [**DEM**] [NP2] > [NP1 **COPULA** NP2]

The 2017 paper quoted says that 是 was always somewhat atypical as a demonstrative, always having had anaphoric reference.